# Get dynamic webpage data using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Can anybody tell how I can get dynamic web page data or content using javascript?

Similar to php function get_file_content()
page_value = get_file_content(http://www.mywebsite.com/page.html);

But it is in javascript.
Is it possible?

Comment: jQuery's `.load()` and `.ajax()` functions are used for loading data from a web server.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ajax/info .  However, this will only send requests back to the origin server unless the remote server has CORS enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)

Example In Javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","Your URL",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>AJAX</h2>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Request data</button>
<div id="myDiv"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

You can also look in [Jquery Ajax](http://www.sitepoint.com/use-jquerys-ajax-function/) [Jquery Ajax Doc](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Example in Jquery [Taken from Here](http://www.jquery4u.com/demos/ajax/)

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'getTwitterFollowers.php',
  type: 'GET',
  data: 'twitterUsername=jquery4u',
  success: function(data) {
    //called when successful
    $('#ajaxphp-results').html(data);
  },
  error: function(e) {
    //called when there is an error
    //console.log(e.message);
  }
});
-----------------------------------------------------
PHP - GET NUMBER FACEBOOK FANS & TWITTER FOLLOWERS
-----------------------------------------------------
< ?php
//get data passed to script
$username = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_GET["twitterUsername"]));

//get twitter followers
$api_page = 'http://twitter.com/users/show/' . $username;
$xml = file_get_contents ( $api_page );
$profile = new SimpleXMLElement ( $xml );
$count = $profile->followers_count;
$tfans = strval ( $count );

//get facebook likes
$fuser = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/140918675956744/'));

//return result
echo "jQuery4u has " . $fuser->likes . " Facebook fans and " . $tfans . " Twitter followers.";
?>
```

For Cross Domain Ajax Call you will require JSONP
Example
jsonp.php

```
<?php
    $callback ='mycallback';

    if(isset($_GET['mycallback']))
    {
        $callback = $_GET['mycallback'];
    }   
    $arr =array();
    $arr['name']="Ravishanker";
    $arr['age']=32; 
    $arr['location']="India";   

    echo $callback.'(' . json_encode($arr) . ')';

?>
```

JQUery Code for JSONP

```
$.ajax({
        url : "http://hayageektest.appspot.com/cross-domain-cors/jsonp.php",
        dataType:"jsonp",
        jsonp:"mycallback",
        success:function(data)
        {
            alert("Name:"+data.name+"nage:"+data.age+"nlocation:"+data.location);
        }
    });
```

Example Taken from [here](http://hayageek.com/cross-domain-ajax-request-jquery/)

Comment: I highly suggest using jQuery's ajax, as this has various improvements and cross-browser reliability fixes.

Comment: By This Process I Can Get The Local Page Or Page in Same Domain But I want to get the external dynamic page.
<code>
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30317015/get-dynamic-webpage-data-using-javascipt",true);
</code>
How can i get external dynamic page data?

Comment: Yes.. by this this way you can process local pages i.e Same domain.. To access pages on another domain `the remote server must have CORS enabled` then only ajax would get results.. Whatever remote server you trying to access thru ajax.. see if CORS is enabled or not

Answer (score 0):

I think i got a perfect solution. This can done by YQL. Here is the code.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var container = $('#show');
      $('.ajaxtrigger').click(function(){

        doAjax($(this).attr('href'));
        return false;
      });
      function doAjax(url){
       alert(url);

var data = "http://ronwe.com/ronwe-marketing-suite/";
        if(url.match('^http')){
          $.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?"+
                    "q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22"+
                    encodeURIComponent(data)+
                    "%22&format=xml'&callback=?",
            function(data){
              if(data.results[0]){
                var data = filterData(data.results[0]);
                container.html(data);

              } else {
                var errormsg = '<p>Error: could not load the page.</p>';
                container.html(errormsg);
              }
            }
          );
        } else {
          $('#target').load(url);
        }
      }
      function filterData(data){
        data = data.replace(/<?\/body[^>]*>/g,'');
        data = data.replace(/[\r|\n]+/g,'');
        data = data.replace(/<--[\S\s]*?-->/g,'');
        data = data.replace(/<noscript[^>]*>[\S\s]*?<\/noscript>/g,'');
        data = data.replace(/<script[^>]*>[\S\s]*?<\/script>/g,'');
        data = data.replace(/<script.*\/>/,'');
        return data;
      }
    });
  </script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <a href="http://ronwe.com/ronwe-marketing-suite/" class="ajaxtrigger loaded">Load Ajax Content<span> (ready.)</span></a>

    <div id="show">
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```